# Disable cookies in embedded eclipse Jetty via vm argements

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

How to disable cookies in embedded eclipse Jetty via vm argements like "-Dorg.eclipse.jetty..."?

Comment: What do you mean "disable cookies"? "Cookies" are just request/response headers that are set/read by your web application itself

Comment: something like here http://www.mojavelinux.com/blog/archives/2006/11/disabling_session_cookies_in_jetty/

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a global property that you can set on the command line to do this within Jetty.  You would need to add that as a property to your embedded jetty usage if you want to toggle it, or just set it to false when you instantiate your session manager.